# Set multiple alarms from Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, alarmmanager, alarm

I'm coding an application. I have a database with `SQLite` and I'm getting row and splint. I want to set multiple alarms, but only first data is shown. Please help me.

```
public void alarm_kur() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    String durum = "0";
    String where = Veritabani.COLUMN_DURUM + "=?";
    String selectquery = "SELECT * FROM " + Veritabani.TABLE_NAME;
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{durum};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(Veritabani.TABLE_NAME, null, where, whereargs, null, null, null, null);
    AlarmManager alarmManager;
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String mesaj = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Veritabani.COLUMN_MESAJ));
            String tel_number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Veritabani.COLUMN_NUMBER));
            String Time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Veritabani.COLUMN_SAAT));
            String Date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Veritabani.COLUMN_TARIH));
            String Id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Veritabani.COLUMN_ID));
            String[] saat_dakika = Time.split(":");
            String[] tarih = Time.split("/");
            int Saat = Integer.parseInt(saat_dakika[0]);
            intDakika = Integer.parseInt(saat_dakika[1]);


            final int _id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
            ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
            PendingIntent appIntent = null;
            for (int say = 0; say < cursor.getCount(); say++) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
                intent.putExtra("tel_number", tel_number);
                intent.putExtra("mesaj", mesaj);
                appIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, say, intent, 0);


               getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
               ,appIntent);
                Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
                calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Saat);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Dakika);
                calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                long sdl = calSet.getTimeInMillis();

                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, sdl, appIntent);
                intentArray.add(appIntent);

            }


        } while (cursor.moveToNext());


    }
}
```

This is the code for setting alarms.

Answer (score 1):

You can use try-finally clause:

```
try {
      while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String ...
                ...
                alarmManager ...
            }

        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move  `ArrayList<PendingIntent> intentArray = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();` outside `do while` loop, it's getting re-instantiated for each row, so you will only get one intent after `do while` code block